# How can css pixels stretch out when zooming in?

Tags: css, viewport, pixel, retina-display, display

Acoording to this article here https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html the CSS pixels start to grow, and now one CSS pixels overlaps several device pixels. According to me if the CSS pixels grow, then I will be able to see more content of the page not less. But when zooming I am able to do the opposite: to see less content. Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is question is correct; as you zoom in, the CSS pixels increase in size. **However**, *because* the CSS pixels increase in size while the viewport remains the **same** size, fewer CSS pixels can be displayed (meaning you *see* fewer CSS pixels).

Consider this in math:

```
              CSS pixels * viewport size = visible pixels

ZOOMED OUT:         1280 * 1024          = 1,310,720
DEFAULT:            1024 * 1024          = 1,048,576
ZOOMED IN:           768 * 1024          =   768,432
```

Hopefully this helps clarify this a little :)

Comment: I think I understand from your explanation. However, in the calculation below, shouldn't the last one be zoomed in instead of zoomed out? Because 768px means the pixels are bigger and thus smaller in number so the resulting number 768,432 is smaller than the default. Or I am wrong somewhere again? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that the best, and the math certainly didn't help illustrate my point in retrospect. Those two numbers *should* be swapped, and I've updated my answer now to cover that. Ironically, I initially had it that way to start with, then swapped it in my confusion. As you zoom, the pixels get **bigger**, so there are **less** of them spread over the **same** area. Hopefully that makes it a little clearer ;)

Comment: I have one more question. The viewport size here is shown in CSS pixels right?